# R: capture the value of the previous row

Tags: r

I have a code which identifies when property ownership has transitioned to a new owner. In the column, transition, the code allocates the value of "1" every time there is a transition and "0" if the property has not transitioned. The "1" is allocated to the new owner of the transition. This helps me capture data of all new buyers.

I need a code, now, which identifies the seller of the property (i.e. the row above the new owner with the value of 1). I believe this is possible with dplyr's lag function, but I am having trouble implementing it.

For example, if there is a transition between A (seller) and B (buyer), I can only currently identify the buyer B (transition=1) but want to identify the seller, too.

Here is the code for buyers:

```
transitions <- transitions %>%
  group_by(property) %>%
  mutate(transition = ifelse(name != dplyr::lag(name), 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like the code for a seller is similar to that of a buyer, only now we want to find the above where the name is different.

```
transitions %>% 
group_by(property) %>%  
mutate(seller = ifelse(lead(transition) == 1 & name!= lead(name), 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I seem to be facing a bit of an issue. This code attributes "1" in the seller column for the buyer, not for the row above the buyer. Could you please assist me?

Comment: Hi @user12801590, you're right and I modified my answer. `seller` now only evaluates to 1 if the _next_ row contains a transition and the name is not equal.

Comment: Hello! I just realized there is a small error with the code. It is allocating the value of "1" to seller in the last year of the property ownership. 

For example, if we have data for a single property between 1998 and 2015, and there is no transition of owner throughout this period, the code will allocate "1" in seller for 2015. I do not know why this is happening.

Comment: Could you give me an example please? If `transition` is 0 in all records of the property, then it should be impossible for `seller` to be 1.

Comment: I've uploaded three examples of where the code isn't working properly, and an example of where it is working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

For me this code worked, using `dplyr::lag()` as well. Note that the name of the seller is present in the first observation, when the transaction is done. If you want it in all the rows your can use `fill`

```
data %>%
  mutate(
    seller = ifelse(transition == 1, lag(name), NA)
  )
```

In the future try using a minimal reproducible example, you do not have to use the whole data frame, just a few rows that capture the problem you are facing.

Comment: Could you please help me with a code where, instead of giving the name of the seller in the transition row, it provides the value of 1 to the seller itself (i.e. the row right above where transition==1)? This way, I will be able to sort for sellers by filtering seller=1 and the buyers by filtering where transition=1. Thank you!